# Obtener dato especifico de un campo en Mysql con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una duda y quisiera que me apoyaran.
**1)** En la tabla que se aprecia en la imagen tengo datos almacenados, pero es el campo **sg_vehiculo** el que me interesa mas. Lo que quiero hacer es obtener un dato especifico de ese grupo que se encuentra almacenado, es decir:
**De:** VOLVO - B4Y-732, M.Benz - B4D-960, Neptune - C0K-960
**Quiero obtener solo por ejemplo:** Neptune - C0K-960

¿Como hago para obtener dicha información?...

**2)** Puedo relacionar el dato que obtenga con el campo **sg_kilometraje**, e imprimirlo asi:
► Neptune - C0K-960 ha recorrido 250 KM

---

[image: Tabla de datos]

Comment: Es extraño que estés almacenando los datos así en la columna `sg_vehiculo`... ¿eso es una lista de vehículos? ¿por qué intentas guardar una lista en un campo? a la larga eso va a ser muyyy problemático. Si para algo tan simple mira ya la lucha que estás teniendo, ¿qué será si te toca contar, hacer estadísticas, borrar, actualizar, etc, para `Neptune - C0K-960`  ... es más, si `C0K-960` es algo como un modelo de vehículo `Neptune` o la matrícula, tu error de diseño es todavía mucho más grave.

Comment: Los datos están guardados de esa manera en la BD debido a que el input del form que envia los datos es tipo "select multiple", Es un form que registra los servicios de transporte realizados, donde en ocasiones se suele enviar mas de 1 bus, por lo cual coloqué la opcion select multiple porque ya tengo una tabla con la lista de todos los vehiculos con los datos que son "tipo, marca, placa".

Comment: Eso no justifica que los guardes así. Es un gravísimo error de diseño que no hará otra cosa que darte muchos problemas. Creo que debes rediseñar la tabla, luego por código puedes obtener y separar los datos para insertarlos o lo que sea. En estos casos, optar por lo que parece el camino más corto por facilidad o por desconocimiento es un grave error y ese camino que parecía corto resulta ser el más largo y casi siempre termina llevando a un callejón sin salida (una base de datos ambigua, lenta, bloqueada, inconsistente, reduntante...). Creo que debes repensar lo que estás haciendo.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por la información. Me podrías mostrar la manera o como deberia de rediseñar la tabla para manejarla correctamente como indicas, me serviría de mucho. Gracias

Comment: Te podría ayudar, pero debes plantear otra pregunta donde expliques el modelo de datos y digas las dificultades o dudas que tienes. Y sería en otro momento, cuando tenga disponibilidad. Algo que ayuda mucho es pensar cada tabla como  una entidad y evitar la redundancia usando IDs. Si `Neptune` es un vehículo, debe aparecer como tal solamente en la tabla `vehiculo`... todos los otros sitios donde debe aparecer, debe ser por su `id` numérico. Lo mismo para los modelos, las matrículas, las ciudades, los clientes, etc. Hablamos de que necesitarás varias tablas.

Answer (score 0):

sg_vehiculo es un campo de texto, no puedes obtener solo una parte con una consulta. Tienes que trabajar esos datos en el backend, o modificar tu tabla para que sg_vehicle se relacione con una tabla picote que contenga los id de cada vehículo.

Answer (score 0):

Obtén el campo de la BD y guárdalo en una variable por ejemplo:

```
$sg_vehiculo = 'todo lo necesario para obtener el campo';
```

En tu BD se observa que cada valor está delimitado por una coma entonces lo vamos a convertir a un array de la siguiente manera:

```
$sg_vehiculo = explode(',',$sg_vehiculo);
```

Si imprimimos `$sg_vehiculos` nos daría el siguiente resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'Volvo - B4Y-732'
    [1] => 'M.Benz - B4D-960'
    [2] => 'Neptune - C0K-960'
)
```

Para imprimir lo que deseas sería de la siguiente manera:

```
echo $sg_vehiculo[2].' ha recorrido '.$sg_kilometraje;
```

Aquí estoy suponiendo que ya obtienes el kilometraje y lo guardas en la variable `$sg_kilometraje`.

[Documentación de explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)